# ajax update to database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to add data to a database and for some reason it does not always work. I'd say 80% of the time it will work and I'll see the result in the database but sometimes its like the script won't run.

here is the ajax :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(function () {
        $('.error').hide();
        $("#success").hide();
        $(".button").click(function () {
          $('.error').hide();
          var name = $("input#name").val();
          if (name == "") {
            $("label#name_error").show();
            $("input#name").focus();
            return false;
          }
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "class/proccess.php",
            data: $("input#name"),
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
              $("#success").fadeIn(200).show();
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
```

here is the html:

```
<div id = "contact_form">
  <form name ="contact" action="">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
      <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required.</label> 
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="send" />
    </fieldset>
    <span id="success"> the name has been updated successfully!</span>  
  </form>
</div>
<div id ="upd"></div>
```

and here is the proccess.php file:

```
<?php
$va = $_POST["name"];
$dbconnection =  mysql_connect('adatabase','someuser','somepw');
  if(!mysql_select_db('some_database', $dbconnection)) {
      echo mysql_error();
  }
    else
    {
        echo 'connection success';
    }
$sql = "INSERT INTO some_db(text) VALUES ('$va')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('erreur sql!'.mysql_error());
if(!$result) {
    echo "not working";
}
else {
    echo "working";
}
?>
```

so how come it does not always insert into the database?

and is there a way to get the result from the php if(!$result) to show in the success part of the ajax?

Comment: For one thing, you have a "ready" handler that sets up a "ready" handler, which may not be the problem but it's pointless.

Comment: return a json, or a unique string code like echo "1", echo "2", then on your success return change to success: function (data) { console.log(data) }, then you can do a easy IF to return a feedback on UI

Comment: **-1** Stop using `mysql_*` functions and learn about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1):

If it is not working sometimes, you need to check the returned string for errors. The right way to do this using AJAX is as follows.

You can include a parameter in your success callback which will fetch the page-result from the PHP.

Instead of

```
 success: function () {
     ...
   }
```

use

```
success: function (data) {
       alert(data);
   }
```

Comment: trying to get an alert(data) returns blank. no text shows on the alert.

Comment: Well, that means the php is returning no text, which is extremely weird. Try just having an echo statement and nothing else in the PHP, as a test. Does the echoed text show up in the alter box?

Comment: Nope! I get nothing back..which is weird.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually passing a jQuery-Object to your PHP-File.

```
$.post("class/proccess.php", { 
name: $("input#name").val() //Pass val() not the whole jQuery-Object!
}, function() { 
/* success */ 
});
```

Comment: If I try $("input#name").val() instead of just $("input#name") I get an empty insert, as if the POST wasnt working.

Answer (score 1):

While you're debugging, make sure MySQL errors are enabled.

In your Javascript for the Ajax success handler, show an alert with the text returned from the call. That way if there's an error with MySQL you'll see it.

Another thing is, could the "text" field be set in the database as UNIQUE? Trying to insert a new record with a duplicate string would fail in that case.

And... the name of the field isn't really 'text' is it?  I would recommend avoiding field names that are the same as the basic data types for MySQL. Just to avoid confusion if no other reason.

Comment: I get a blank alert statement when I try to check for alert(data). But It does go through and insert into the database. The text field is not named text and is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax call to:

```
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "class/proccess.php",
        data: {name : $("input#name").val()},
        cache: false,
        success: function () {
          $("#success").fadeIn(200).show();

        }
```

So that $_POST['name'] is set to the value of your input box.

Also, as suggested, you should change your mysql functions to [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) functions to help protect against sql injections.

Comment: I think you've downvoted our posts, to get yours on top, am I right or am I right?

Comment: Haha I wish, but I can honestly say that wasn't me.  Not that desperate for "karma."

Comment: I suspect you're right... Unless it was really obvious, I think most people would add a comment to indicate what they think is wrong.

Comment: I shall counter their downvotes with my own upvotes.  Justice be damned!